# Windows Form Misaligned

Tags: winforms

I've created a Windows Form application.  On may laptop screen, the form looks fine.  However, on my main monitor, the right edge of the form is misaligned (screenshots below).  Any idea how I can fix this?[image: Form comparison]

Comment: This isn't a WinForms issue - it's a bug (kinda) in how Windows renders the nonclient area on high-DPI monitors when the process is not `PerMonitorV2`-aware. The best fix here would be to update your app to support `PerMonitorV2` DPI.

Comment: You probably have noticed that the second image shows a blurry window. That's the effect of virtualization when the Window / Process is not DpiAware. As suggested, make your app DpiAware. .NET Framework app need to opt in, .NET 5+ apps, though DpiAware by default, should change their DpiAwareness to `PerMonitorV2`, the default is `SystemAware` (long to explain, but that's the functionality that is actually optimized at this time)

Comment: Thanks @Jimi and Dai. I found [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0) which explains updating the app manifest to support High HDI.  But it warns:  

Important
In previous versions of the .NET Framework, you used the manifest to add high DPI support. This approach is no longer recommended, since it overrides settings defined on the app.config file.

Do you recommend updating the manifest file still? I don't see any other recommendations by Microsoft.

Comment: If you're targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1+ (better 4.8+), you should use `app.config`, since this is the expected behavior. `app.manifest` can still be used, but you need to update it in a way that is not exactly well documented. You may end up with an app that appears to be DpiAware as specified (`PerMonitorV2`), but it's actually not. Better use the former -- If possible, move to .NET 7+